# How can i configure a static ipv6-prefix to one linux host

Tags: routing, linux-networking, ipv6

I have a virtual Linux server (Kubuntu 14.04) and i will ask the hosting provider for a complete /64-Prefix for this machine (at the moment i have 4 individual IPv6-Addresses).

How do i configure the entire /64-Prefix to a physical interface at my server?
I mean, the server must announcing itself to the LAN (inside the hosting provider) as being responsible for the entire /64-Prefix and all other hosts on the LAN (including the border-router with the connection to the real/global Internet) should know that all IP-Packets with a destination-ip-address inside this prefix must be delivered to the MAC-Address of my server.

Example:
My hosting provider owns the prefix 2001:db8::/32 for further delegating subnets of it to all its costumers. Then my hosting provider gives me 2001:db8:dead:beef::/64 for my server.
How do i configure the Linux on my server that it accept incoming connections on all IP-Addresses inside my /64-Prefix and (even more important) announce itself as the responsible host for all IP-Addresses in the entire Range 2001:db8:dead:beef:0000:0000:0000:0000**--**2001:db8:dead:beef:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF?

All that i have found in the Internet are examples for configuring (multiple) individual/single IPv6-Addresses (each with full 128 significant Bits) for a specific host by appropriate commands in /etc/network/interfaces but i can not find an example for configuring a complete IPv6-Prefix (with below 128 significant Bits) for a specific host.

Second question:
What do the host for advertising that he is responsible for a complete IPv6-Prefix and not only for some individual IPv6-Adresses? What type of ICMPv6 Advertisement-Messages are used for this purpose?

Comment: I do not think that my question is a duplicate of "Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?", my question means primary the visibility of my prefix for the physical Ethernet-Network outside of my server for all other hosts in this Ethernet-Network, including the border-router to the global Internet. The primary focus of my question is the advertisement mechanism of Linux for announcing itself as responsible for a complete Prefix not only for some/multiple individual IPv6-Addresses.

Comment: They are not exactly duplicates. In order to do this right, you need a routed prefix. You only need a single IPv6 address within the link prefix, and the provider need to route your routed prefix to that single IPv6 address. Once the routed prefix has been configured, you can refer to that other question, since it should cover the rest.

Comment: Here is a related question, which may also be relevant to you: http://serverfault.com/questions/590038/adding-a-whole-ipv6-64-block-to-an-network-interface-on-debian

Comment: I still do not understand what a "routed prefix" is. As fas as i know my hosting provider give me a 64/-Prefix for my server, in my opinion it means i have 2^64 individual IPv6-Addresses for my own use. And my question means: how do i configure the Linux at my server for correct announcing of the entire Prefix (all 2^64 IP-Addresses but not individually but as a whole) and how do this works on wire-level (what ICMPv6-Pakets are used for announcing a complete Prefix on a single MAC-Address). Your hints to the other questions are interesting, thank you, but do not completely answer my question.

Comment: I can not find a description about the differences between "routed prefix" and "link prefix", should i open a new question for this topic?

Comment: I think that would be very relevant as a separate question. A system administrator who has only been working with IPv4 and not IPv6 could easily be unfamiliar with the terms. It is not that the terms mean anything differently in IPv6, but rather that shortage of IPv4 addresses have lead to all sort of hacks that happen to have made those terms not be used often when talking about IPv4. And additionally there is AFAIK no autoconfiguration mechanism for routed prefixes in IPv4.

Comment: is asked: http://serverfault.com/questions/684455/ipv6-differences-between-routed-prefix-and-link-prefix

Comment: and answered http://serverfault.com/a/684572/214507