# forward ipv6 allocation over a tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, tunnel

I have a VPS with a /64 IPv6 allocation, but the /64 isn't forwarded to the main ip of the VPS, I must add extra IPs on the eth0 interface if I want to use them.  What I'd like to do is to forward some of these IPs and permit a computer over an ssh tunnel to use them.

What I'm not sure to do is how to bind the ip to the eth0 interface on the vps and still allow it on the remote network.  The best solution I cancome up with is putting eth0 and the tun device on a bridge, and then having the remote host just add the ip to the tun device, but there must be a better way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPv6: differences between "routed prefix" and "link prefix"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/684455/ipv6-differences-between-routed-prefix-and-link-prefix)

Answer (score -2):

for anyone else coming across this question, the answer is to use

```
ip -6 neigh add proxy the_ip_here dev eth0
```