# IPv6 /56 subnetting to Virtual Machines

Tags: ipv6

My network provider has allocated me a IPv6 /56.  My goal is to give a /64 to each virtual machine I have.  They told me they would route the /56 to my CentOS Xen server and I would have to handle the routing to the VMs.

Do I assign 2001:db8:1111:15::2 to the host server's network config with ::1 being the gateway?

Message from provider:

> We have routed the IPv6 addresses to you vlan.
>   2001:db8:1111:15::1/122
>   Then we routed
>   2001:db8:2222:2000::/56 to 2001:db8:1111:15::2

Answer (score 2):

Yes, my reading of the provider's response is also that you configure your physical interface with `2001:db8:1111:15::2/122` using `2001:db8:1111:15::1` as the gateway.

Using a `/122` for the link prefix is a bit unusual. The recommended practice is to use a `/64`. But you shouldn't configure a shorter prefix than the provider told you to, so I recommend you stick with `/122` like they said.

The good news is that since you got a routed prefix it isn't a big deal for you how the provider chose to configure that link prefix. An earlier question has more details on [link prefixes and routed prefixes](https://serverfault.com/q/684455/214507).

The routed prefix `2001:db8:2222:2000::/56` can be subdivided into 256 link prefixes allowing for up to 256 VMs. Though you might want to set aside some `/60`s in case you find a need for a routed prefix on one of the VMs.

For example you could use `2001:db8:2222:2000::/64` through `2001:db8:2222:207f::/64` as link prefixes to allow for 128 VMs. And use `2001:db8:2222:2080::/60` through `2001:db8:2222:20f0::/60` as routed prefixes allowing for up to 16 of your VMs to get a routed `/60` for themselves.