# Adding more than 32 IPs on a Proxmox (v6) VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, proxmox

I use Proxmox v6 and I want to add more than 32 IPs (network device) on a VM but via the interface it is not possible. Currently, I go through the Proxmox interface and I go to -> Hardware -> Add -> Network Device, but beyond 32 the "Network device" option is grayed out and I cannot add more. 'other. Via the command line pvesh create it's the same, beyond 32 this generates an error ... Can anyone help me ? Is it possible to route more IPs to a VM from the host?

Comment: You can assign more than one IP address per interface / device. You dont need more than 32 devices, you only need 1.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple IP addresses for one interface.

Either individual addresses and each do neighbor discovery, or by [routing a prefix](https://serverfault.com/a/684572/241174) to the host.