# Why is my router's ipv6 address different from the lan prefix?

Tags: routing, ipv6

I have done some research:

I think I know what global unicast addresses are.
My ISP grants me `2605:6000:FFC0:7D:C4CD:A25A:777A:xxxx/64` (at least that is what my router reports as its "IPv6 address" (TP-Link AX1800).

Further down the page I see my "Lan Address Prefix" as `2603:8080:2C05:209A::` with it reporting an address of `2603:8080:2C05:209A:EA48:B8FF:FE1F:6DF0/64`. While this confuses me (this is a range, right?), **my question is:**

Why isn't my lan address prefix `2605:6000:FFC0:7D::/64`? I would love to have global unicast addresses for each host/interface.

From what I understand, each of my devices can get a /64? They don't need that! They can get a /80 and I can have subnets, right?

I understand why I am getting addresses on my PC like:

```
    inet6 2603:8080:2c05:209a:14a9:d676:62f6:xxxx/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 2603:8080:2c05:209a:7d63:7c25:af1d:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 300sec preferred_lft 300sec
    inet6 fe80::56a3:67f2:bc72:52c7/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But why do I have 2? Why are they not under the WAN IP prefix?

If this is something the router doesn't support, I don't mind using OpenWRT.

Related?: https://serverfault.com/a/751852/983001

Comment: This is something you need to ask your ISP, it's their network and their design and implementation.

Comment: You have a network that is delegated to you for use on your LAN. The WAN network is for the link between you and the ISP, but you have one or more LAN networks, too. This is not like using IPv4 with NAT, your router routes packets between networks, so your LAN and WAN networks are different. The WAN network is a transit network, and the ISP sends any packets destined to your LAN network to your WAN address. The LAN addresses are Global addresses.