# IP Range - Subnet network configuration on CentOS 6.4

Tags: networking, centos, iptables, linux-networking, ip-aliasing

I have problems to configure an subnet /25 on an vps with CentOs 6.4 have tried different version.

The original eth0 settings are:

```
DEVICE=eth0
#HWADDR=de:8f:24:e9:7b:04
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=64e110dd-d5db-4d6c-b99a-9da73ecc26c5
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=84.60.42.181
NETMASK=255.255.255.224
```

Other eth's doesn't exist. Now I tried to configure the range with creating a range network file

```
vi ifcfg-eth0-range0
```

Then in the file

```
IPADDR_START=84.180.231.1
IPADDR_END=84.180.231.254
CLONENUM_START=0
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
```

Save and closed... and `network restart`.

But it doesn't work. Still can't ping the IPs from outside. Perhaps someone can help me.

Comment: Have you tried without the netmask argument in the range file?

Comment: Ok I have tried it now. I get back Determining if ip address 84.180.231.1 is already in use for device eth0...
Determining if ip address 84.180.231.2 is already in use for device eth0...
Determining if ip address 84.180.231.3 is already in use for device eth0...
...
But ping to IP is still not possible...

Comment: What IP are you trying to ping from? Localhost?

Comment: For example 84.180.231.1. From outside.

Comment: I don't understand... if I add a ip temporaly an with ip a add 84.180.231.1/24 dev eth0 I can ping and use the ip. But to add 128 IPs on this way is not so effective

Comment: I'm wondering where you are pinging from, the same machine?  Since you're assigning a full /24 to the interface, I imagine you'll only be able to ping from the machine itself..

Comment: Ping the IP direct on the vps work. But from outside not.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/209203/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/590038 may be of interest

Comment: Considering you are assigning from `.1` to `.254`, it doesn't leave much range outside for another machine, even a router, which could then take traffic in and out of that subnet.

Comment: @NickW Why that? There is an .0 and .255 also....

Comment: IN a /24, those are not used, .255 is broadcast, .0 is the net identifier.. [read this](http://cisconet.com/tcpip/tcpip-general/100-ip-addressing-ending-0-or-255.html), in a larger net those are valid addresses.

Comment: The eth0 has for example this infos:  inet addr:219.99.233.200  Bcast:219.99.233.223  Mask:255.255.255.224

Comment: The rangefile is creating this infos:  inet addr:84.180.231.1  Bcast:84.180.231.31  Mask:255.255.255.224 if I remove the netmask argument from the file.

Comment: Yeah, because you created a 32 IP range, what you will want to do is something like this `IPADDR_START=84.180.231.1
IPADDR_END=84.180.231.254
CLONENUM_START=4` then set up a static machine with `84.180.231.1 NETMASK 255.255.255.0` and you should be able to ping.. fromt here you can decide how to set up your network.

Answer (score 0):

84.180.231.1 is not inside 84.60.42.181/25, hope you made it intentionally.

Make sure the rest of the world knows that the specific server has that range of IP, that you have routing configured properly both at your default gateway and that you configured default gw properly on the server.

Also, don't forget to check icmp on your firewall(s)