# how to use ipv6 subnet (2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/96) for outbound connection from linux?

Tags: linux, debian, google-cloud-platform, ipv6, debian-buster

how to use `2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/96`  subnet for outbound connection from linux?

I'm trying to use something like this `curl --interface 2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1:5fff:8 ifconfig.co` in GCP VM

this is working if I add with `ip -6 addr add 2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1:5fff:8/128 dev ens4`, but I want to use all address of `2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/96` or at least `2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/112`

but if I add with `ip -6 addr add 2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1:5fff::/112 dev ens4`, curl is not working, giving error with `(99: Cannot assign requested address)`

Comment: Who gave you that IP address?

Comment: Are you trying to add VM's to a primary network interface or secondary network interface? Make sure the IPv6 is enabled in the subnet first and next in the VM.
Refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc#subnet-enable-ipv6) for more information on enabling IPv6 and refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#ipv6-addresses) for details on IPv6.

Comment: @GoliNikitha as I stated above, if I use /128 its working fine, but I can't a way to use any ip in that range, its enabled in subnet, vm as /96 to main interface. I followed same links what you shared.

Comment: @vidarlo its in GCP

Answer (score 1):

After many tries with different options, finally adding addr and route along with enabling `net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind` doing trick

```
ip add add local 2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/96 dev lo
ip route add local 2302:1400:3010:3731:0:1/96 dev ens4
sysctl net.ipv6.ip_nonlocal_bind=1
```

Reference: https://serverfault.com/a/971732/225853

> make this question duplicate :(