# Multiple IPv6 addresses added to interface, now IPv6 not working on my server

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6, ethernet, interface

I got /64 IPv6 block from my server provider.

When I add few IPv6 addresses (maybe 10 or 20) to network interface. Everything works fine about IPv6 network.

When I'm added above 500+ IPv6 addresses to network interface. My server IPv6 network not working.

I'm used to this type of command line to add IP address to network interface.

```
sudo ifconfig em1 inet6 add 2001:bd8:24ac:36c8::/128
```

I need to use at least 1000 IPv6 addresses on my server.

Please help me, how to solve this issue?

**Note: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit server**

Thank you.

Comment: I'd start over and see exactly when the number of addresses causes a failure.

Comment: @JimB I have seen this problem show up once I reached approximately 4000 addresses. The number of addresses needed to trigger the problem was not consistent.

Comment: Would the the AnyIP feature be of use to you?  http://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface

Comment: So it dies at 4000, but not the 1000 you need?  Are you adding the entire block?

Comment: @JimB The problem I saw happened at approximately 4000 addresses total across all interfaces. When it happened the machine would stop responding to neighbor discovery but otherwise remain functional. Since that machine was configured with both native and tunneled addresses, it remained reachable over the tunnel but not with native addresses. I needed a /96 and at first I tried adding the addresses dynamically whenever they were needed. In the end I used a local route instead.