# IPv6 multiple addresses on an interface

Tags: ipv6, subnet

I used to assign different IPv6 addresses for different services on the same server this way I can filter what can be accessed from where, which is improves network security.

I just realized that the only thing I might be doing wrong is that I choose these addresses from the same /64 prefix. It is not a problem to filter out connections from the outside world on the gateway, but the isolation may be bad between the server processes.

If I understand correctly, /64 is the smallest prefix that is recommended be assigned. If I want to disallow (using packet filter on the server) the services to communicate with each other then they should not be in the same subnet so I have to assign the addresses from different /64 prefixes.

Am I right in this?

Or it is no problem using serveral /120 prefixes for example to not needlessly waste the IP range?

Should it work **as per standard**, or the behavior is implementation-specific?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Inside* your network, I guess, technically, you can do anything you like. You can assign /120's if you really want to. But you shouldn't.

But is there actually a problem you're trying to solve here? There should be zero issue assigning multiple IPv6 addresses from the same /64 to a single server. In fact you can [assign an *entire* /64](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface) or larger if you want to (and there are reasons why you would want to do this).

Now, that all said and done, it appears that you are mostly concerned with intra-server comunication. Here's the thing though - even if you assign IP addresses from different networks intra-server communication is still going to work. Because a server will only route to a default gateway (and thus pass through a network level firewall) if it has no route to the target - but in your case it has a *direct* route to the target because the IP addresses are all on the same machine.

Secondly, addressing this network communication is only one small part of the pie. If you're concerned about security in depth, what's to stop an attacker (or a rogue application) from just reading and writing directly to the memory space of the other application? Or the disk?

The most common way to enforce that sort of segregation is via Virtual Machines. Or containers/jails.

Comment: I am concerned with just the intra-server communication. You are right that there is a direct route inside the system, but if the addresses are from different subnets, then a routing decision takes place which you can control (using iptables in linux for example). You are right that it does not solve all security issues, but it might solve one of them. The whole system is as much secure as less possibilities you leave.

Comment: @GáborMóczik If you have iptables, you can restrict intra-server connections by firewalling on the loopback device.  Normally this isn't done as it is easy to break things.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 is built around the assumption of /64 (or larger) subnets. If you make subnets smaller than that, you need to really do your research to know what features you may break. Some manufacturers have coded IPv6 implementations to assume /64 as the base size.

I would also like to add that you do not need to assign a subnet to do IP filtering. You are correct that inter subnet communication would trigger the traffic to be routed through the gateway, but if all of your services are on the same machine, you could look into doing iptables rules or similar on that machine to filter inter-service communication. This could be done on a /128 or per host basis.

The last thing to look at is if these services need to be segregated, they should maybe be on separate machines, VMs, or (Docker) containers. This would probably be my recomendation, but it is further from what you are asking for.