# ip route add local not working

Tags: linux, debian, ipv6

I'm trying use all my /64 block IPv6 IPs on my machine. I ran into this post on serverfault

[Can I bind a (large) block of addresses to an interface?](https://serverfault.com/questions/209203/can-i-bind-a-large-block-of-addresses-to-an-interface)

I have a VPS from Vultr running Debian 9

Below is the image related to my IPv6 block

[image]

I executed the following command

```
ip route add local 2001:19f0:9002:a32::/64 dev lo
```

but I can not connect with any of the IPv6 IPs to ssh

Comment: `lo` might be the wrong network device. Did you try the ethernet device?

Comment: @blafasel when I replace lo with ens3 I get "RTNETLINK answers: File exists
"

Comment: @blafasel Routes of type `local` only work if they are configured on the `lo` interface. The problem is that the prefix is a link prefix and not a routed prefix. The linked question has a workaround for that.